Movie that has two characters fight villain in boiler/cremation room
English language movie, either late 1990's or early 2000's. Likely made in US. I think the movie was a thriller/drama/action, any of the three or a mixture of one or two of those.
Story points:

The villain likely had medium-long black hair and wore black
The villain enters a room of an elderly woman with a big mole on her lower face as she's sleeping on her bed, the villain picks up an object (maybe a toy or music box, something ?) and says something mocking.
The two characters enter a hospital morgue and check on the elderly woman's body. One character looked to be slightly older than the second character. The second character apparently suffered a case of "house caught in massive fire". There's even a scene where he was a boy, he looked into a door's keyhole and watched where the fire started, blazing and stuff.
The villain appears with a gun and tries to kill them. He misses and a few of the shots hit the elderly womans corpse. The villain escapes as through the hospital, violently shoving patients and staff.
The final showdown happens in the hospitals boiler/cremation room. The first protagonist is eventually shoved outside the room, whilst the second character and villain are trapped as the room then explodes in fire.
The ending has the first character with his family/friends, whilst the second character is shown to have survived, standing outside the rain wearing a hoodie. He then meets a woman, and they both flirt.

